# Capturing numbers in a string and storing in data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am a bit green with python and I have been fooling around with pandas and numpy for some months now. It is my first post here, so please tell me if I am missing something.

I am looking to extract atom counts from molecular formulas stored as a column in a data frame. A string would look like this

```
C55H85N17O25S4
```

The problem is, my current code extracts some atoms fine such as C, H, N or O but not S (or Cl or Br) and I do not see why.

My current code look like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myfile = "whatever.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(myfile, sep='|', header=0)

#create the columns for atoms
atoms = ['C', 'H', 'O', 'N', 'Cl','S','Br']
for col in atoms:
    data[col] = np.nan

#parse molecular_formula for atoms using regex and add the number into the corresponding column
for col in atoms:
    data[col]= pd.np.where(data.molecular_formula.str.contains(col), data.molecular_formula.str.extract(re.escape(col) + r'(\d{1,})'), '0')
```

I am aware that I will not capture a number but a NaN if there is no number after a letter in my string but I am fine with this. I can replace NaN by '1' as long as I get '0' if the atom was not contained in the molecular formula (there is probably a more elegant way to do it though).

For this example my current output is:

```
molecular_formula   C       H       O       N       Cl      S      Br
C55H85N17O25S4      55      85      25      17      0       0      0
```

While I would like:

```
molecular_formula   C       H       O       N       Cl      S      Br
C55H85N17O25S4      55      85      25      17      0       4      0
```

I think the problem lies in my str.extract() as if I change my code to

```
data[col]= pd.np.where(data.molecular_formula.str.contains(col), 1, 0)
```

I do get something like:

```
molecular_formula   C       H       O       N       Cl      S      Br
C55H85N17O25S4      1       1       1       1       0       1      0
```

**UPDATE:** I have added some extra lines to count single atoms that should be counted as '1' when it is at the end of the molecular formula or in the middle of it but not followed by a number.

```
#When the single atom is at the end of the molecular formula:
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'[C]$') == True, 'C'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'[H]$') == True, 'H'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'[S]$') == True, 'S'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'[O]$') == True, 'O'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'[N]$') == True, 'N'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'[C][l]$') == True, 'Cl'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'[N][a]$') == True, 'Na'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'[B][r]$') == True, 'Br'] = 1

#When the singe atom is somewhere inside the molecular formula:
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'.*[C][l]\D') == True, 'Cl'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'.*[C]\D') == True, 'C'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'.*[B][r]\D') == True, 'Br'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'.*[N][a]\D') == True, 'Na'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'.*[N]\D') == True, 'N'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'.*[H]\D') == True, 'H'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'.*[S]\D') == True, 'S'] = 1
data.loc[data.molecular_formula.str.contains(r'.*[O]\D') == True, 'O'] = 1

#Convert the atom columns into int:
for col in atoms:
    data[col] = pd.to_numeric(data[col])
```

It is quick and dirty and I will have to loop through these and use lazy regex to solve the issues of atoms with two letters like 'Br' or 'Na'.
But these lines combined with the answer of @jxc give the output that I wanted.

Comment: what is the version of your Pandas? if 0.18.0+, you can use extractall(): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html

Comment: I just gave it a shot, thanks. 
The issue is that the output is then quite hard to work with. I really want new columns with the name of the corresponding atom added to the original dataframe with an int for every atom. I don't really see how I can do that with str.extractall(). That would require mapping the output of str.extractall() to new columns in my original dataframe and since different molecules can have different atoms and they are not necessarily in the same position in the formula (the first 2 are always C and H, but the the 3rd can be Br, Cl, N or O etc), it gets messy.

Comment: you can use **reindex()** to fix missing atoms, check the answers I added.

Comment: For the regex pattern, you don't need to use the named capturing groups **(?P<name>)** i.e. you can just use `(C|H|O|N|Cl|S|Br)(\d+)`, then the generated df1 will have two default columns [0,1], you can then rename column or just use df1[0], df1[1] instead of df1.atom and df1.cnt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using pandas 0.18.0+, you can try [extractall()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to retrieve all atom+count combos and then use pivot() or unstack() to get atoms in the columns. After that reindex() and fillna() to get missing atoms: see below example (tested on Pandas 0.23.4):

**UPDATE:** On Pandas version 0.24+, the pd.pivot() function yield **KeyError** and some change on this function made it not compatible with version 0.23.4. Use `unstack()` instead in the new code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('C55H85N17O25S4',),('C23H65',),(None,), (None,), ('C22H16ClN3OS2',)
         , ('C37H42Cl2N2O6',), ('C21H30BrNO4',), ('C11H13ClN2',), ('C34H53NaO8',), ('A0',)
    ],columns=['molecular_formula'])
#  molecular_formula
#0    C55H85N17O25S4
#1            C23H65
#2              None
#3              None
#4     C22H16ClN3OS2
#5     C37H42Cl2N2O6
#6       C21H30BrNO4
#7        C11H13ClN2
#8        C34H53NaO8
#9                A0

# list of concerned atoms 
atoms = ['C', 'H', 'O', 'N', 'Cl','S','Br']

# regeex pattern
atom_ptn = r'(?P<atom>' + r'|'.join(atoms) + r')(?P<cnt>\d+)'
print(atom_ptn)
#(?P<atom>C|H|O|N|Cl|S|Br)(?P<cnt>\d+)

# extract the combo of atom vs number and pivot them into desired table format 
df1 = df.molecular_formula.str.extractall(atom_ptn) \
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True) \
        .set_index('atom', append=True) \
        .unstack(1)

# remove the level-0 from the column indexing
df1.columns = [ c[1] for c in df1.columns ]

# reindex df1 and join the result with the original df, then fillna() 
df.join(df1.reindex(columns=atoms)).fillna({c:0 for c in atoms}, downcast='infer')
#  molecular_formula   C   H   O   N Cl  S  Br
#0    C55H85N17O25S4  55  85  25  17  0  4   0
#1            C23H65  23  65   0   0  0  0   0
#2              None   0   0   0   0  0  0   0
#3              None   0   0   0   0  0  0   0
#4     C22H16ClN3OS2  22  16   0   3  0  2   0
#5     C37H42Cl2N2O6  37  42   6   2  2  0   0
#6       C21H30BrNO4  21  30   4   0  0  0   0
#7        C11H13ClN2  11  13   0   2  0  0   0
#8        C34H53NaO8  34  53   8   0  0  0   0
#9                A0   0   0   0   0  0  0   0
```

AS of Pandas **0.24.0**, we can use [DataFrame.droplevel()](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html?highlight=droplevel#pandas.DataFrame.droplevel) and then do all in one chain:

```
df.join(df.molecular_formula.str.extractall(atom_ptn) 
          .droplevel(1)
          .set_index('atom', append=True) 
          .unstack(1) 
          .droplevel(0, axis=1) 
          .reindex(columns=atoms) 
   ).fillna({c:0 for c in atoms}, downcast='infer')
```

**UPDATE-2 (on 5/13/2019):**

Per comments, atoms with missing numbers should be assigned with a constant `1`. see below two modifications:

1. the regex:

   - `cnt` should allow EMPTY string, thus: from `(?P<cnt>\d+)` to `(?P<cnt>\d*)`
   - `atom` must be sorted so that longer string are tested before shorter ones, this is important since regex alternation matches the sub-patterns from left to right. this is to make sure *Cl* is test before *C*, otherwise *Cl* will never get matched.

     ```
     # sort the list of atoms based on their length
     atoms_sorted = [ i[0] for i in sorted([(k, len(k)) for k in atoms], key=lambda x: -x[1]) ]

     # the new pattern based on list of atoms_sorted and \d* on cnt
     atom_ptn = r'(?P<atom>' + r'|'.join(atoms_sorted) + r')(?P<cnt>\d*)'
     print(atom_ptn)
     #(?P<atom>Cl|Br|C|H|O|N|S)(?P<cnt>\d*)
     ```

   To test it out. you can try: `df.molecular_formula.str.extractall(atom_ptn)` by using *atom_ptn* created by both sorted and unsorted list.
2. fillna(1) for all atoms matching 0 digits from the above regex pattern, see below:

   ```
   df.join(df.molecular_formula.str.extractall(atom_ptn)
             .fillna(1)
             .droplevel(1)
             .set_index('atom', append=True)
             .unstack(1)
             .droplevel(0, axis=1)
             .reindex(columns=atoms)
      ).fillna({c:0 for c in atoms}, downcast='infer')
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am almost there. 
I just have a problem with an 'not in index' KeyError. This toy dataframe is close to what I have and encounters the same error:

 `df = pd.DataFrame([('C55H85N17O25S4',),('C23H65',),(None,), (None,), ('C22H16ClN3OS2',), ('C37H42Cl2N2O6',), ('C21H30BrNO4',), ('C11H13ClN2',), ('C34H53NaO8',) ],columns=['molecular_formula'])`

I thought it was the NaN that were the issue at first, but it is not the case (I can remove them from the dataframe and the problem persists). Any idea?

Comment: Worth to mention: I have used `(C|H|O|N|Cl|S|Br)(\d+)` and `lst = df1.pivot(index=df1.index, columns=0, values=1)`

There was a mistake in your code btw, it is `lst = df1.pivot()` and not `lst = pd.pivot()`. 

:)

Comment: @thiR, guess it might be from the version compatible issue. I tested the code on Debian-9, Python 3.7.2 and Pandas 0.23.4 which works fine with your updated dataframe and also `pd.pivot()`. Just checked the document, looks `pd.pivot(data, index=..)` now needs the data to be mandatory. so if you are using the latest Pandas, I guess you should also be fine with: `pd.pivot(df1, index=df1.index, columns=0, values=1)`.

Comment: @thiR, I am not able to test the Pandas 0.24 right now, but I will add an alternative with findall() soon when I get time.

Comment: good to know! I might just create an other environment with these versions and see if it works. I am currently using Python 3.7.3 with Pandas 0.24.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: @thiR, I tested 0.24.1 on a docker container, now I am getting the KeyError on pivot() function. I just adjusted the code to use unstack() now which is working fine on 0.24.1, please check if that works for you.

Comment: Tried in a fresh environment with Python 3.7.3 and Pandas 0.23.4 and your code works perfectly indeed. I'm really curious what is going wrong with Pandas 0.24.2.

Edit: I will check with unstack().

Comment: @thiR, I think it's from the `pivot()` which is a less-used function. most of its functionalities can be handled by other alternatives. maybe it will be disconnected in the future??. Pandas 0.24.2 does have many good improvement though. BTW. can you check if the new code with unstack() work for your environment?

Comment: It works! The sleeker DataFrame.droplevel() too. Thanks a bunch.

Only one problem though: singular atoms like 'Br' or 'N' in observation #6 are not counted. It was one of my initial issues (these are not captured by the regex).

Comment: @thiR, glad it worked. since both 'Br' and 'N' are not followed by a number, they are just skipped from `extractall()` but picked up by `reindex()`. if you need Br, N and O all set to 4 on #6, I think it will be hard with a simple regex pattern..

Comment: I would actually need 1 on #6. I have added some lines after your code to capture these "single atoms". It is quite ugly ATM and I will try to loop through it and use lazy regex instead whenever I have time.

Comment: @thiR, if it's a constant '1', then it can be fixed with some small modification. I will check it back after 9AM when I get to my desktop.

Comment: @thiR, please check the section `UPDATE-2 (on 5/13/2019)`.

Comment: `UPDATE2` works perfectly in my environment! Thanks.
You've been using nested list comprehension for `atoms_sorted`, correct?

Comment: @thiR, yes, in fact, you can do it much simpler with `atoms_sorted = sorted(atoms, key=len, reverse=True)`. I am from Perl background, so it's nature for me to use the map-sort-map way to sort a list in the first place. For a small list like `atoms`, I think the simple one should be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

string = "C55H85N17O25S4"

ATOM_REGEX = r'([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d*)'

list_of_atoms = re.findall(ATOM_REGEX,string)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list_of_atoms).T
df.index=["Elements","Coefficient"]

print(df)
```

Output:
[image]

Check out [this parser](https://github.com/Zapaan/python-chemical-formula-parser/blob/master/parser.py) if you have chemical formulas that are strings which include brackets or parenthesis